# How to send a Mat in OpenCV from Java client to C++ server

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, udp

First of all, thanks for your attention.

I make a program that send a Mat in OpenCV from Java client to C++ server.

Currently, it communicates using UDP sockets.

If you know how to do that, could you give us some advice or examples?

Comment: Grab the Mat `.data` with the cols, rows and padding and send it thru your socket.

Comment: @Aram What is .data??

Comment: In C++ the .data member holds the internal matrix array, maybe there was something similar in Java. Another thing you could do is fill a buffer (Java array) with the matrix values, ie iterate the matrix, and then pass that buffer through your socket plus the row and cols, then in C++ construct a Mat with that, its not pretty but its likely to work.

Comment: @Aram Oh, Thank you, I'll try that

Comment: @Aram Hi, Aram. I have a question. Why do I send the padding of mat server?? Thank you beforehand

Comment: Mats can have padding, this means that a row might have a few more bytes, if they have padding you have to change the step in the Mat constructor. https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a